# datetime() gives assertion error in zipline

Tags: python, pandas

When using pd.Timestamp() I get this:

> Liabraries imported
> '''

```
%matplotlib inline

import zipline
from zipline import run_algorithm
from zipline.api import order_target_percent, symbol, set_commission, set_slippage, schedule_function, date_rules, time_rules
from datetime import date, datetime
import pytz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pyfolio as pf
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from scipy import stats
from zipline.finance.commission import PerDollar
from zipline.finance.slippage import VolumeShareSlippage, FixedSlippage
```

'''

> Model Settings

```
intial_portfolio = 100000
momentum_window = 125
minimum_momentum = 40
portfolio_size = 30
vola_window = 20

enable_commission = True 
commission_pct = 0.001 
enable_slippage = True 
slippage_volume_limit = 0.025
slippage_impact = 0.05
```

'''

> Function to calculate annual regression slope R multiplied

```
def momentum_score(ts):

  x = np.arange(len(ts))

  log_ts = np.log(ts)

  slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, log_ts)

  annualized_slope = (np.power(np.exp(slope), 252) - 1) * 100 

  score = annualized_slope * (r_value ** 2) 

  return score
```

> Function using standard deviation as a measure of volitility

```
def volatility(ts):
  return ts.pct_change().rolling(vola_window).std().iloc[-1]

def output_progress(context):

  today = zipline.api.get_datetime().date()

  perf_pct = (context.portfolio.portfolio_value / context.last_month) - 1

  print("{} - Last Month Result: {:.2%}".format(today, perf_pct))

  context.last_month = context.portfolio.portfolio_value
```

'''

> Reading file from disk, scheduling trades, setting commission and slippage

```
def initialize(context):

  if enable_commission:
    comm_model = PerDollar(cost=commission_pct) 
  else:
    comm_model = PerDollar(cost=0.0) 
  set_commission(comm_model)
  if enable_slippage: slippage_model=VolumeShareSlippage(volume_limit=slippage_volume_limit,
price_impact=slippage_impact) 
  else:
    slippage_model=FixedSlippage(spread=0.0) 
  set_slippage(slippage_model)

  context.last_month = intial_portfolio

  context.index_members = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/My Project Folder/index members/sp500.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0], engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)

  schedule_function(
    func=rebalance, 
    date_rule=date_rules.month_start(), 
    time_rule=time_rules.market_open()
  )
```

'''

> The balancing trades function

```
def rebalance(context, data):

  output_progress(context)

  today = zipline.api.get_datetime()

  all_prior = context.index_members.loc[context.index_members.index < today]

  latest_day = all_prior.iloc[-1,0]

  list_of_tickers = latest_day.split(',')

  todays_universe = [symbol(ticker) for ticker in list_of_tickers]

  todays_universe = [ 
    symbol(ticker) for ticker in
    context.index_members.loc[context.index_members.index < today].iloc[-1,0].split(',')
  ]

  hist = data.history(todays_universe, "close", momentum_window,"1d")

  ranking_table = hist.apply(momentum_score).sort_values(ascending=False)

  kept_positions = list(context.portfolio.positions.keys()) 
  for security in context.portfolio.positions:
    if (security not in todays_universe): 
      order_target_percent(security, 0.0) 
      kept_positions.remove(security)
    elif ranking_table[security] < minimum_momentum: 
      order_target_percent(security, 0.0) 
      kept_positions.remove(security)

  replacement_stocks = portfolio_size - len(kept_positions) 
  buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]
  new_portfolio = pd.concat(
    (buy_list,
    ranking_table.loc[ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)])
  )
  buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]

  vola_table = hist[new_portfolio.index].apply(volatility) 
  inv_vola_table = 1 / vola_table
  sum_inv_vola = np.sum(inv_vola_table) 
  vola_target_weights = inv_vola_table / sum_inv_vola
  for security, rank in new_portfolio.iteritems(): 
    weight = vola_target_weights[security]
    if security in kept_positions:
      order_target_percent(security, weight)
    else:
      if ranking_table[security] > minimum_momentum: 
        order_target_percent(security, weight)
```

'''

> Function to calculate performance metrics of model

```
def analyze(context, perf):
  perf['max'] = perf.portfolio_value.cummax() 
  perf['dd'] = (perf.portfolio_value / perf['max']) - 1 
  maxdd = perf['dd'].min()

  ann_ret = (np.power((perf.portfolio_value.iloc[-1] / perf.portfolio_value.iloc[0]),(252 / len(perf)))) - 1

  print("Annualized Return: {:.2%} Max Drawdown: {:.2%}".format(ann_ret, maxdd))

  return
```

'''

> Setting Start and End dates of simulation

```
start_date = pd.Timestamp('1996-1-2', tz='utc')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-31', tz='utc')
```

> Running the simulation

```
results = run_algorithm(
    start=start_date,
    end=end_date, 
    initialize=initialize, 
    analyze=analyze, 
    capital_base=intial_portfolio, 
    data_frequency = 'daily', 
    bundle='eod_data')
```

'''

### I get these error messages:

> TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects.

'''

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    539             try:
--> 540                 self._check_compatible_with(other)
    541             except (TypeError, IncompatibleFrequency) as err:

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in _check_compatible_with(self, other, setitem)
    501             return
--> 502         self._assert_tzawareness_compat(other)
    503         if setitem:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in _assert_tzawareness_compat(self, other)
    691                 raise TypeError(
--> 692                     "Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects."
    693                 )

TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

'''

> InvalidComparison: 1997-01-02 21:00:00+00:00

'''

```
InvalidComparison                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   1007         try:
-> 1008             other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
   1009         except InvalidComparison:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    542                 # e.g. tzawareness mismatch
--> 543                 raise InvalidComparison(other) from err
    544 

InvalidComparison: 1996-01-02 21:00:00+00:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
'''
    
>TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp
```

'''

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp

'''

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-efa4e42dcada> in <module>()
    192     capital_base=intial_portfolio,
    193     data_frequency = 'daily',
--> 194     bundle='eod_data')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py in run_algorithm(start, end, initialize, capital_base, handle_data, before_trading_start, analyze, data_frequency, bundle, bundle_timestamp, trading_calendar, metrics_set, benchmark_returns, default_extension, extensions, strict_extensions, environ, custom_loader, blotter)
    417         blotter=blotter,
    418         custom_loader=custom_loader,
--> 419         benchmark_spec=benchmark_spec,
    420     )
    421 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py in _run(handle_data, initialize, before_trading_start, analyze, algofile, algotext, defines, data_frequency, capital_base, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, environ, blotter, custom_loader, benchmark_spec)
    223             else {
    224                 "algo_filename": getattr(algofile, "name", "<algorithm>"),
--> 225                 "script": algotext,
    226             },
    227         ).run()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/algorithm.py in run(self, data_portal)
    621         try:
    622             perfs = []
--> 623             for perf in self.get_generator():
    624                 perfs.append(perf)
    625 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/gens/tradesimulation.py in transform(self)
    226             for dt, action in self.clock:
    227                 if action == BAR:
--> 228                     for capital_change_packet in every_bar(dt):
    229                         yield capital_change_packet
    230                 elif action == SESSION_START:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/gens/tradesimulation.py in every_bar(dt_to_use, current_data, handle_data)
    141                 metrics_tracker.process_commission(commission)
    142 
--> 143             handle_data(algo, current_data, dt_to_use)
    144 
    145             # grab any new orders from the blotter, then clear the list.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/utils/events.py in handle_data(self, context, data, dt)
    207                     context,
    208                     data,
--> 209                     dt,
    210                 )
    211 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zipline/utils/events.py in handle_data(self, context, data, dt)
    227         """
    228         if self.rule.should_trigger(dt):
--> 229             self.callback(context, data)
    230 
    231 

<ipython-input-2-efa4e42dcada> in rebalance(context, data)
    107 
    108   # Second, get the index makeup for all days prior to today.
--> 109   all_prior = context.index_members.loc[context.index_members.index < today]
    110 
    111   # Now let's snag the first column of the last, i.e. latest, entry.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/extension.py in wrapper(self, other)
    154 
    155         op = getattr(self._data, opname)
--> 156         return op(other)
    157 
    158     wrapper.__name__ = opname

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in __lt__(self, other)
     38     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__lt__")
     39     def __lt__(self, other):
---> 40         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.lt)
     41 
     42     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__le__")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   1008             other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
   1009         except InvalidComparison:
-> 1010             return invalid_comparison(self, other, op)
   1011 
   1012         dtype = getattr(other, "dtype", None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/invalid.py in invalid_comparison(left, right, op)
     32     else:
     33         typ = type(right).__name__
---> 34         raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     35     return res_values
     36 

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp
```

'''

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reverting. I will add more code and the traceback asap

Comment: Thanks again for reverting. I will post more detail of the error in due course ! I did not have much time today. I appreciate the help !

Comment: Good day, I have added more code and the traceback to the error messages and gave the specifications/description of my environment and system. Code is executed using Google Colab . I would appreciate all the help I can get in resolving my issue. Thank you in advance